# Restrict varnish purge requests to wordpress logged in users

Tags: wordpress, varnish, request

I need to restrict varnish purge requests to wordpress logged in users, so that when one user updates a post or page, the purge request sent to varnish can take effect. I have debian, apache2, varnish 4.0, and 'Varnish HTTP Purge' plugin installed. All works well, but the problem is anyone on the internet can send a ' curl -X PURGE "example.com" ' command and purge my cache. I know I can restrict the IP's that can send purge requests in the 'acl' clause in my 'default.vcl', but the problem is that the IP's of users that must send purge requests are dynamic, so they change from time to time.

Comment: If the _plugin_ is sending the purge requests, then only the local server's IP addresses need to be listed! Users shouldn't need to manually send purge requests with curl at all.

Comment: Yes, only the plugin is sending the purge requests. The fact is the server itself has a changing IP, and I wouldn't want to manually set the IPs in the 'acl' clause every time the IP changes.

Comment: What's wrong with localhost? That never changes.

Comment: It doesn't work with localhost. It only works if I add the server's public IPv4 and IPv6 addresses. And those are the ones that change periodically.